# Hiding a particular image from RSS

Tags: css, xml, rss, blogger

I have a Blogger-powered site (alwaysspanish.com) and offer RSS feed via http://www.alwaysspanish.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss.

On my blog posts, I always include a small, 100px image at the beginning wrapped inside a "postthumb" class. This class has been styled to be visible only on index pages so that the thumbnail is visible only as a part of post-snippets in such pages as archives, category, etc. On the other hand, it won't be visible on the full-post page.

While this rule works fine on the website display, it doesn't when it comes to my RSS feed. The RSS XML appears to ignore all CSS styling. Is there any way to force RSS into honoring at least this one styling because I really don't want to display the first image (the thumbnail styled as .postthumb) on my post feed? I hope to get some solution around programmatically tweaking the RSS XML before it's fed to the readers.

Comment: Don't forget that RSS is just data. How it'll be rendered depends on the reader used by the end user. The only solid solution is to actually remove the picture but, given that you are using a third-party service, it's probably not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be to open the RSS in an iframe and then load the CSS inside that iframe with javascript. Simplest solution thought

```
<iframe name="frame" src="link/to/your/rss" height="100%" width="100%" onload="contentLoaded();"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
var contentLoaded = function() {

    var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
    cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
    frames['frame'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);   

}
```

Notice: This only works if the domain of the iframe matches your domain...

Comment: This goes in my HTML code, right? My concern is will this script really be able to govern how the feed appears in the reader (app or even email)?

Comment: The above code is HTML. The javascript comes in a vrapped <script></script> tag. This is a script to display the RSS feed via iframe, you can then add a style link to the frame which will render CSS for its content.

Comment: Thanks, David. One last, though, won't this end up displaying the feed "in my page" depending on which part of the page the iframe is plugged in? What I need is some way to render the CSS styling in the feed itself when it appears, say, in an email subscription or an RSS reader. I don't want to display the RSS itself on my site.

Comment: Sure it does. But instead of http://your-rss.com you could make it http://your-site.com?rss=your-rss and then your site will become the rss feed (depends some server side coding). Sorry to tell but another solution doesnt exist.. (well maybe there is, but everything else would need a good knowledge in regular expressions)